# How many concurrent connection does IE9 have while in IE7 mode

Tags: internet-explorer, concurrency, internet-explorer-9, connection

Does anyone know how many concurrent connections IE 9 allows while in other browser modes?

Since I'm asking, how concurrent connections do all IE browsers and other the top browsers have?

Actually having issues in Chrome, i think its a concurrency problem, someone suggested that it should happen in IE& as well, but i do not have IE7 installed.
I did try it in IE9 set to IE7 browser mode, and it worked. SO was wondering if IE7 mode was using IE9's concurrent connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 and IE9 have 6 concurrent connections on broadband.
IE10 has 8 concurrent connections.

http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/07/21/internet-explorer-8-and-maximum-concurrent-connections.aspx

http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network

Answer (score 6):

The above poster is correct, IE9 has similar behaviour to IE8; IE9 allows 6 concurrent connections, except when on VPN or dialup, in which case it allows two.

A good overview of the state of affairs is at http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network under the Connections per Hostname column.