# Java needed memory for new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

I have an application which massively creates threads. As result I get an **OutOfMemoryError**. My idea is to wait until there is enough free space to create the next **Thread**. But therefore I need to know how many memory I need to create a thread and if this amount of memory is available. Is there a way to get the amount of memory a thread needs? And how can I determine if this amount of memory is available?

What I've already tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    while(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() +
        Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() < MEMORY_THRESHOLD) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.wait(10);
        }
    }
    Thread t = new Thread(new Task(links.get(i)));
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

But even when I use 100MB as threshold I get an **OutOfMemoryError**.

Comment: I'm not an expert here ,but I feel like you're comparing apples to oranges with the line : `.maxMemory() - untime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`  , maxMemory and totalMemory sound different to me

Comment: Why would you create a massive amount of threads?

Comment: @Coffee this should be the memory the JVM can allocate, when I just use freeMemory(), it blocks before the first thread is created.

Comment: An application that "massively creates threads" sounds a bit scary to me. Creating threads is expensive as you've found, which is why thread pools exist. How many threads are you creating? If you are creating so many threads that you're causing memory pressure that is a serious problem. I would suggest that you take a step back and reconsider your solution. The book "Java Concurrency in Practice" is a good resource here.

Comment: In addition to Sleiman Jneidi's answer: I would specifically suggest `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(reasonableNumber)` where the number depends on whether tasks are cpu or io bound. More tasks than 100% load will slow down the process.

Comment: @zapl I download data from different servers. The threads are waiting the most time for this data.

Comment: If you assume that you're not on google fibre and the servers you connect to aren't terribly slow: Already a few (2 or 3) connections can result in 100% load on your network interface, adding more and more tasks will not increase the efficiency. Testing is key though. If files are small and there is a lot of waiting for connection establishment, you may want to have more. Since that depends a lot on parameters you can't control you could consider making that an option somewhere. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522789/how-many-concurrent-connection-does-ie9-have-while-in-ie7-mode

Comment: @kaetzacoatl Anytime you have lots of threads waiting, you know you're doing something terribly wrong. You don't need "active waiting". It doesn't take a thread to wait.

Comment: @zapl so I have the best performance when I create only 6-8 threads? And each additional thread will not increase the performance?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Back when threads first became popular, multiprocessor computers did not exist outside of University research departments.  Threads were invented as a way to organize a program (especially a real-time, embedded program) that had to wait for many different asynchronous inputs.  Instead of having one big event loop that polled for each of the different possible inputs, the program would have one thread to wait on each different input source.

Comment: @jameslarge What something was invented for does not tell us anything about what it should be used for.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, True, but it _does_ tell us something that it _can_ be used for.  If you discover a compelling new use for hammers, does that mean I must stop reaching for my hammer when I want to drive a nail?  Using different threads to perform different I/O bound task still has all of the same advantages and all of the same drawbacks that it had back in the day.  The fact that threads can now also be used for multiprocessing doesn't change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you go and delete this code and use a `ThreadPool` instead. What you trying to do is quite hard and you should be using the higher abstraction you have to do multithreading or you don't do it at all.

[Check out](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-%E2%80%93-part-7) Executors, currently they are the higher abstraction. 
If your tasks are compute bound then `ForkJoin` in Java 7 is your friend and you don't need to bother about the pool size as long as you know how to recursively divide your problem into subproblems.

Comment: Your solution works, but I still don't know how mny threads I can create. Executors.newFixedThreadPool() asks me for the maximum amount of threads, but thats exactly what I don't know.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl somewhere between the number of cpu cores and twice that, more and performance degrades needlessly. If you have tons of threads waiting around all day long use an async framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information on the question in order to suggest an optimal solution.

Typically you may need to create many more threads than your actual CPU cores when you have expensive I/O operations. Judging from the `links` variable, this might be one of these cases, but as others suggested creating too many threads usually suggests a bad design. It might even get your system to run out of available resources.

Even when going over the network, your bandwidth is fixed, so unless you have direct access to an internet backbone it is highly unlikely that you'll get any performance benefit as most websites should respond with high speed.

Having said that, even if you slowed down thread creation you cannot control how much memory a thread will consume and at what time. i.e. All of your threads might start downloading data at the same time and even if you don't create any new ones, you will still run out of memory.

In conclusion, follow what others users suggested:

- Use an `ExecutorService`
- Read a bit more about Threads (Java Concurrency in practice, is a very good source)
- Think why you are creating so many threads? Why do you expect that whatever you do will work faster?

PS. It would also help if you included why you need to create so many threads in your question