# ServerSocket connection with more than one client

Tags: java, sockets

Folks. I'm newbie in network programming and come across the following issue. I need to write the server which can maintain a connection with more than one client simultaneously. What I've written is the following:

`Main` class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ConnectionUtils.waitForClients();
    }
}
```

`ConnectionUtils` class:

```
public class ConnectionUtils {

    private static ServerSocket server; 

    static{
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(54321);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private static Runnable acceptor = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Client c = new Client(server.accept());
                new Thread(acceptor).start();
                c.sendLine("Hello client \n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };

    public static void waitForClients(){
        Thread clientAcceptor = new Thread(acceptor);
        clientAcceptor.start();
    }
}
```

and it works, more-or-less. But what is the downside of that approach? I suspect there're too much disadvantage, but I can't catch their.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you creating an infinite number of `threads` where `threads` are expensive resources. You should be using a ThreadPool to limit the number of threads created in your program.
Consider using `Executors` instead of using this low-level code, [In Oracle documentation about Executors, there is an example similar to what you doing. Check it out!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html?is-external=true)

Comment: Couldn't you explain how we can determine the size of the thread_pool created by Executor. We don't know what number of clients will be connected.

Comment: Not all clients are supposed to create connections simultaneously, and if it happens they could be queued. Not happy with that? Expect out of memory exceptions. Check this answer out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678072/java-needed-memory-for-new-thread/26678106#26678106

Answer (score 1):

Heh interesting. I wouldn't expect it to be wrong but it sure isn't how I'd write it.
I'd probably have 1 thread in an infinite (semi-infinite with stop condition) loop that accepts and spawn threads, rather than something that looks like a recursive method but isn't. However as far as I can see it's not wrong.

Having said that, if you don't use your main thread for anything, why not do something like (and keep in mind i'm not a network programmer either)

```
public class ConnectionUtils {
    protected boolean stop = false;
    public static void waitForClients() {
        while (!stop) {
            Client c = new Client(server.accept());
            new Thread(new ClientDelegate(c)).start();
        }
    }
}

public static class ClientDelegate implements Runnable {
    private Client client;
    public ClientDelegate(Client c) { this.client = c; }
    public static void run() {
        c.sendLine("Hello client\n");
    }
}
```